# PHP cURL JSESSIONID Cookie Error

Tags: php, cookies, curl, session-cookies

I wan't to login to a ssl site with my php script.
If i load the page with the post login form i get a session cookie with the value

```
JSESSIONID=E180962D04FFCCDCEFF3ACA063347C23; Path=/qisserver; Secure
```

And the source code of the page shows the session id in the form post destination:

```
<form method="post" action="https://foo.bar/baz;jsessionid=E180962D04FFCCDCEFF3ACA063347C23?state=user&amp;type=1&amp;category=auth.login&amp;startpage=portal.vm" name="loginform">
```

If I login i get a new session cookie with a location:

```
JSESSIONID=91E63CBCE0E309D5ACE2F609453E0D63; Path=/qisserver; Secure
Location=https://foo.bar/baz;jsessionid=91E63CBCE0E309D5ACE2F609453E0D63?state=user&type=0&category=menu.browse&startpage=portal.vm
```

This is the process in my web browser so far. 
Now I wrote a php/curl script, which first connects, collects the first cookie and extracts the jsessionid value because it is a part of the form action url.

Second my script should login and store the new cookie but I get an error. I can't tell you more about the error.

Here is my php:

```
<?php


$username = "foo";
$password = "blubb";

# Define the target and referer web pages
$target = "https://foo.bar/rds?state=user&type=0";
$ref    = "https://foo.bar/rds?state=user&type=0";


$useragent = "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0"; 


// GET JSESSION ID COOKIE START   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////

$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");   // Cookie management.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE); // remove body 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);    // Timeout sek
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);             // Target site
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);            // Referer value
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);           // Minimize logs
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    // No certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);             // Limit redirections to four
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string

    # Create return array
    $header   = curl_exec($ch); 


    # Close PHP/CURL handle
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
    $cookie = findSessionID($header);


function findSessionID($html){
    //extract session id value
    $begin = 'JSESSIONID=';

    $starnr = strpos($html,$begin);
    $starnr += strlen($begin);

    $laenge = 32;
    $id= substr($html,$starnr,$laenge); 
    return $id;
}
// GET JSESSION ID COOKIE END   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////


sleep(2);


// LOGIN START  //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////

$formurl ="https://foo.bar/qisserver/rds?;jsessionid=".$cookie."&state=user&amp;type=1&amp;category=auth.login&amp;startpage=portal.vm";
$query_string = "username=".$username."&submit=%A0Ok%A0&password=".$password;

echo"<br> Rufe URL:   ". $formurl ." auf <br> mit Querystring:   ". $query_string ."<br>";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, FALSE); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, FALSE); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $formurl);          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);   // Include head as needed
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
    # Create return array
    $html   = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $html;

// LOGIN END  //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////   //////////


?>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: If you can't tell more about the error, or provide the URL you are trying to log into, there isn't much we can do to help IMO.

Comment: The url is behind a vpn and about the error i just know "Error in modul user". It's not my server, so that's all i know.

Comment: The exact error: Error in modul user. You are not logged in. java.lang.Exception

Comment: It seems to be a cookie problem. I saved a local copy of the login page and removed the post url jsessionid. This works fine in a browser. Maybe it's a problem with the location in the cookie? This is not stored in the cookie jar, but in the cookie in my browser